# SQL Plus "case" keyword

Tags: sql

Can anyone help me with the proper syntax for a "case" statement using SQL Plus?

```
Select 
sum(case "REQUEST AGE" when >= 60 then 1 else 0) as "60+ Days",
sum(case "REQUEST AGE"  when >= 30 and case when "REQUEST AGE" < 60 then 1 else 0) as "30-    60 Days",
sum (case "REQUEST AGE" when < 30 then 1 else 0) as "Less Than 30 Days",
"SECTOR"
FROM Schema.APPDATA
Where Schema.APPDATA."SECTOR" like '%X%'
```

I'm relatively new to SQL and I have never written such a query. I would like a sum of a case when the column request age is greater than 60, between 30 and 60 and less than 30 as 3 columns grouped by column sector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `CASE WHEN [expression]... THEN` rather than `CASE [variable] WHEN [value] THEN ...` :

```
Select 
sum(case WHEN "REQUEST AGE" >= 60 then 1 else 0 end) as "60+ Days",
....
```

Also, it seems that `count` is more appropriate in your case than `sum` - you won't need `else` at all.

Comment: I needed this as well as the next answer, so thank you as well

Answer (score 1):

Each of the `CASE` statements must terminate with `END` inside the `()`.  You can use the `CASE WHEN <condition> THEN` syntax here:

```
Select 
  sum(case when "REQUEST AGE" >= 60 then 1 else 0 END) as "60+ Days",
  /* And in here, don't repeat the CASE keyword. Both parts of the expression are connected by AND */
  sum(case when "REQUEST AGE" >= 30 and "REQUEST AGE" < 60 then 1 else 0 END) as "30-    60 Days",
  sum (case when "REQUEST AGE" < 30 then 1 else 0 END) as "Less Than 30 Days",
  "SECTOR"
FROM Schema.APPDATA
Where Schema.APPDATA."SECTOR" like '%X%'
```